# Proving a partial differential identity

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^n$. Then for $k=1,2,3, \dots$ $ \left(\dfrac{\partial ^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r}\right)^{k-1}(r^{2k-1}U)  = \left(\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial r}\right)^{k}\left(r^{2k}U_{r}\right)$.

Here I tried prove using mathematical induction. For $k=1$, result is true. But for higher derivatives I'm getting lost.

Comment: Can you show your attempt to the induction step? Assuming  the statement $P(k)$ and then trying to show the statement $P(k+1)$.

Comment: What is $U_r$? Is it $U_r(x)=U(rx)$ or is it a typo?

Comment: @JackT $U_r= \frac{\partial U}{\partial r}$